# Unable to reference app.config in .NET Framework library referenced by a .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, app-config

I have a .NET framework library which has to use some of the config settings which was previously being referenced from a .NET framework Web API and used its `web.config` for resolving the values.

This library is currently being referenced from a .NET Core Web API, as the config in .NET Core is in json format (`appsettings.json`). What do you think would be the optimal way to pass the config values to the library in this new situation?

An explanation regarding how the config is made available to referenced projects would be appreciated.

Can I have a separate config file in the referenced .NET framework library rather than using the one from the .NET Core API?

I tried installing the options library in the .net framework and used DI to pass the values to the framework class utilizing the config but this is not populating the config.

Comment: There are quite a few existing articles on .NET Config strings (using alternative, multiple files, etc) available on Stack Overflow now.  I suggest that you start searching for them to see what information you can glean.

Comment: You should avoid using a .NET Framework class library in a .NET Core project. That eliminates all such troubles. Contact the vendor and let them provide you a .NET Core compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core does not use app.config/web.config whether you target .NET Framework or not. This is a problem with the library, itself, as it shouldn't actually be accessing any sort of config itself directly. That creates an implementation dependency in the library that limits the scope of where and how you can use it, i.e. such as in an ASP.NET Core project, now.

Libraries should only ever rely on abstractions. The app that uses those libraries provides the concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I ported my .NET Framework library to a .NET Core library as I found other methods to be too cumbersome.
[Porting code from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)